# Noise sometimes

Tags: sound

I have an Intel i5 6500, with a gigabyte H110M-H motherboard,Ubuntu 16.04. Sometimes when hearing music, there is a noise, it stays 10-15 seconds (sometimes even more), and then goes. If I update the kernel, Could it solve the problem? Is it safe to upload? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of noise? Does I sound like static or corruption overlayed in top of the normal music, as if somebody were playing with the wire? Or does it interrupt it entirely, or play some other arbitrary noise?

Comment: Also, does the noise stop if you open Audacity?

Comment: The music continues playing, it sound like corruption, a "shhhh". I will try to open Audacity to test it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but it's like static noise.